# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation Energy leak issues

Tags: ios, swift, clgeocoder

I am using a CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation and when it is ran, I get "very high" energy consumption and a bit of Overhead. Here's my code:

```
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        var currentLatCoord = Double()
        if manager.location?.coordinate.latitude != nil {
            currentLatCoord = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
        } else {
            currentLatCoord = 0.0
            print("oops!")
        }

        var currentLongCoord = Double()
        if manager.location?.coordinate.longitude != nil {
            currentLongCoord = (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
        } else {
            currentLongCoord = 0.0
            print("oops!")
        }

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: currentLatCoord, longitude: currentLongCoord)) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("oops!")
                print(error)
                return
            }

            let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!
            var placeMark: CLPlacemark

            placeMark = placeArray![0]

            if let thoroughfare = placeMark.addressDictionary?["Thoroughfare"] as? String {
                self.locationLabel.text = thoroughfare
            } else {
                self.locationLabel.text = "Error!"
                print("oops!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the debugger:
[image: Debugger]

If anyone could find out why, and I searched all over for the reasoning behind this and couldn't find it, please let me know!

Comment: So you're running the `manager` regardless, but seeing high energy impact only if you throw in the `reverseGeocodeLocation` calls?

Comment: Yes, correct. Only when reverseGeocodeLocation is called.